# passing parameter with ngroute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my

angularroute.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="AngularApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var AngApp = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngRoute']);
        AngApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/Route1/:ID', {
                    templateUrl:'Route1.html',
                    controller:'Route1'

                })
                .when('/Route2', {
                    templateUrl: 'Route2.html',
                    controller:'Route2'
                })

                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });

    </script>

            </head>
            <body>

                <p>Routing Explained</p>
                <a href="#Route1/100">Route1</a><br>
                <a href="#Route2">Route2</a>
                <div ng-view>

                </div>

                <script src="Route.js"></script>       


            </body>
            </html>
```

the Route.js file contains.

```
angular.module('Route1').controller('Route1', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.ID = $routeParams.ID;
});

angular.module('Route2').controller('Route2', function () {
});
```

Route1.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Route1">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-controller="Route1">


    {{ID}}

    {{4+10}}

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is it loads the page but i can not receive get the parameter value , on route1.html ,the expression also do not get evaluated .
what could be the problem?
thanks.

Comment: Maybe try to include angular.js in your HTML page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove everything that's not needed from your route template. Only the content that you added in your body of the template is required.

That will be included by angular into ng-view with the controller that you have configured in your route. It's a partial and not a complete html file.

Also your `route.js` code is not correct. You could create a module `angular.module('route', []).controller('route1Controller', function(){...})` and use it as dependency in your app.

With-out the brackets like you did in your `route.js` you're getting a module that's already defined.

Please have a look at your updated code below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ru5yhz26/).

```js
var AngApp = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngRoute'])
 .controller('Route1Controller', Route1Controller)
 .controller('Route2Controller', Route2Controller);

AngApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Route1/:ID', {
        templateUrl:'Route1.html',
        controller:'Route1Controller'

    })
        .when('/Route2', {
        templateUrl: 'Route2.html',
        controller:'Route2Controller'
    })

        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

function Route1Controller($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.ID = $routeParams.ID;
}

function Route2Controller($scope) {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="AngularApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="Route1.html">
        Route1
        {{ID}}

        {{4+10}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="Route2.html">
        Route2

        {{4+10}}
    </script>
<p>Routing Explained</p>
                <a href="#Route1/100">Route1</a><br/>
                <a href="#Route2">Route2</a>
                <div ng-view>

                </div>
    </div>
```