# Angular JS problems with Ng-Route, Gulp, and Json

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm pretty new to the world of front end development and I'm working through my first project with AngularJS. I'm also using Yeoman, Gulp, Bower to set up my project, which is also bran new to me... I've kind of crafted a build from the yo generator Gulp Angular and put my own personal touches to it. I'm sure I did more harm than good :p but I'm learning.

Anyways I've been coding all day and am really stumped why my project is having trouble when I use the ng-route. The home display works correctly but when I try to click on a link to a deeper page it just refreshes back to the home. I'm using Json files rather than a server and the Gulp Angular set up has all my files compiled to another folder when launching a server. Is there any chance the issue could lie within the compiler?

I'm starting to go crazy so I think I'm gonna call it quits for the night but if anyone has the time and the generosity to look over my github repo I would be over joyed :)

Thanks

https://github.com/jleibham/BhamDesigns.git

App Module

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

      var bhamDesignsApp = angular.module('bhamDesignsApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngRoute', 'mm.foundation', 'appControllers']);

        bhamDesignsApp.config(['$routeProvider',
          function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
              when('/projects', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html',
                controller: 'ProjectsController'
              }).
              when('/projects/:projectId', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html',
                controller: 'GalleryController'
              }).
              otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/projects'
              });
          }]);

    })();
```

App Controller

```
(function() {

'use strict';

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('app/json/projects.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.projects = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = '-year';

}]);

appControllers.controller('GalleryController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;
}]);

})();
```

Comment: You didn't specify which links, but in your projects.html, you have an `ng-repeat` over `project in projects` with links to `<a href="#/json/galleries/{{project.id}}">`. That url doesn't match either of the routes in your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong url and your routes do not recognize the url you do call with your href, so it redirects you. In you are going to call this:

`href="#/json/galleries/(what ever the project.id is)`

Then your routing should look similar to this:

`when('/json/galleries/:projectId', { /// the rest of your code`

You are going to want to use [$routeParameters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) with ngRoute. [here is a great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068511/passing-parameter-with-ngroute)