# How to add custom string to angular application url without effecting the normal functioning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I have an angular application working with angular ui-router. When I run the application from server the url is like `localhost/..../index.html`

After I click on any state the url changes to 
`localhost/.../index.html#[whateverStateClicked]` which is normal.

But now I wanted to add some application specific custom string after index.html something like this `localhost/.../index.html/appString` when the application starts and something like `localhost/.../index.html/appString#[whateverStateClick]` upon click of any state and want the application to function in the same way as when the appString is not present.

This appString will be updated during the usage of application or simply bound to a scope variable for updation which shouldn't affect the normal flow.

Comment: Sample plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/Xw408MLlce36s3sxjFCl?p=preview

Comment: You need to look into routing with parameters. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068511/passing-parameter-with-ngroute).

Comment: Thanks @Evilzebra $routeParams helped me solve the problem

Comment: No problem! Would be appreciated if you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive custom variables within the URL by using [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) and  [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).

Setup the router `with/your/:customVariable` and you can easily set your custom string.