# Want to show specific row data in a different page using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

```
<a href='#/viewCampaign' ng-click="viewCampaign(campaignData)">View</a>
```

In my controller.js file, I have defined the ng-click function
I am getting clicked row record in `campaignData`

```
$scope.viewCampaign = function(campaignData){
    $scope.id = campaignData.campaign_id;
    console.log('View campaign:: '+$scope.id);
  }
});
```

And I am switching the view of specific campaign data using ngRoute
Which I have done as follows.

```
.when('/viewCampaign', {
  templateUrl: './campaign-detail.html'
})
```

Now, what should I do to show the record in `./campaign-detail.html` 
Kindly help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: start with `<a href='#/viewCampaign'`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068511/passing-parameter-with-ngroute

Comment: Yeah, thanks.
That was the typing mistake.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for this can be:

when you are calling `viewCampaign` function using `ng-click`, then store that data in some service let say `campaignDataService`.

```
$scope.viewCampaign = function(campaignData){
    $scope.id = campaignData.campaign_id;
    console.log('View campaign:: '+$scope.id);
    // calling campaignDataService here to store data inside that
  }
});
```

change route as:

```
.when('/viewCampaign', {
  template: '<campaign-detail/>',
})
```

changing templateUrl to template and using `directive` in place of template will help you.

In `campaign-detail directive` associate a `controller` and inject `campaignDataService` which contains the required data.
That data you can easily use in the html linked with `campaign-detail directive`.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem!