# How do i pass dynamic title and description by controller for ervery product detail page using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass dynamic title and description by controller for every product detail page using angular js.

HTML :

```
<title>{{page.title}}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{page.description}}">
```

Routing Js :

```
$routeProvider.
 when('/product/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/product.php',
    controller: 'ProductController'
})
```

Controller Js :

```
function ProductController($scope) 
{
    $http.get("api/product/1")
    .then(function(response) {
       $scope.page.title = response.data.title;
       $scope.page.description = response.data.description;
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing parameter with ngroute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068511/passing-parameter-with-ngroute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$routeParams` service to grab `id` value from route, and the create an API url dynamically. Most appropriate way to deal with this would be move out the data retrieval code inside `resolve` function of route. This way you will also make sure that you're preventing page to be display until `page` related call gets executed.

```
$routeProvider.
 when('/product/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/product.php',
    controller: 'ProductController',
    resolve: {
       page: ['$http', $routeParams, function($http, $routeParams) {
           return $http.get("api/product/"+ $routeParams.id ).then(function(response) {
               return response.data;
           })
       }
    }
})
```

Then inside controller use

```
function ProductController($scope, page) {
    function init() {
        $scope.page = page
    }
    init();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Parkar